# Yandex with Google Play Policies

Tags: android, google-play, яндекс-метрика, ads

После добавления **Yandex** монетизации в приложение (альтернатива **AdMob**, если не отображается реклама) и публикации его в **Play Google**, отклонили **Безопасность данных**. Само обновление было опубликовано. Без Яндекса все было в порядке.

[image: скирншот сообщения]

из библиотек добавлял только

```
    implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobileads:5.0.0-alpha.2'
```

Метрику не добавлял. Но заметил, что когда запускаешь устройство для тестирования, то в процессах (Logcat) видно не только само приложение, но и метрику.

Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: Вроде как вам надо где-то в консоли гугла описать что приложение в т.ч. собирает данные для яндекса. По идее достаточно в список всех библиотек, что собирают данные добавить Яндекс и дать ссылку на его документ, где они поясняют что с данными делают

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я указал это в политике конфиденциальности.

Comment: А перечисленное в сообщении гугла у вас явно прописано? Сбор "тут то что у вас на скрине показано и что я не могу скопировать, т.к. это картинка а не текст"?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да это картинка, скриншот письма. Да, я это перечислил в Безопасности Данных.